# Should I use a content management system?

Tags: content-management-system, c1-cms

This question has been bugging me for almost a week now. I've gone ahead and started using Composite C1(since I already had some MVC3 code). I'll outline my high-level requirements:

- User Profiles (Log in/ Log out/ Activity history/ gamification etc.)
- Profile pages for Tools (Need this for storing help documents, training videos, comments for various  softwares)
- Forums (I need to analyze threads and perform sentiment analysis so i need the data with me and not hosted on a third party like nabble)
- Classifieds with intuitive matchmaking for task seekers and providers (based on certain rules)

Since I'm new to using a CMS I'm not sure if I would actually end up using anything off the shelf. Looks to me like I'll have to build a custom component for every feature so I'm thinking is it better to just go ahead and code this myself (ASP.Net MVC3 application).

Will i save considerable time and effort (assuming a decent learning curve for Composite as well) if I go with C1 compared to coding this myself?

Answer (score 1):

no doubt, you will still code for those things you want done, but, the advantage of having a CMS is that it will be easier to manage. Remember it's a management tool. It will give you a UI where you can upload the pages ,and where exactly in a particular page (middle , bottom etc) plus more. One CMS I've used is dotnetnuke .
You can check it here. 
http://www.dotnetnuke.com/ -->(it will give you templates like of that in the site plus more. You can even make one yourself)

Comment: I compared DNN to C1 and felt the C1 is the more popular choice. Also, since C1 offered MVC3 integration, I chose it over DNN.

Comment: I can also back up the use of C1.  One of my gripes with CMS solutions is that you often have to sacrifice flexibility, and in many cases building complex custom modules to integrate into them can be taxing.  Not so with Composite - their architecture is a breath of fresh air (when coming from a developer perspective, I can't speak for users who are more front-end/design orientated).  I have found it really easy to integrate my current projects into Composite - they can live in a semi-integrated mode which is awesome.  I get to use all my coding still. :)